# Restore partition table changed by accident while disk in use

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, mbr

I managed to change partition table on my main HDD. Now, I'm afraid to reboot, because I do not want to lose my data.

Here is what GParted says:

[image]

And when I try to recover data:

[image]

Which is completely correct.

How can I prevent the changes I made being definitively written to disk? And how can I get my partition table (msdos) back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `testdisk` I solved the problem. I ran it with `sudo testdisk`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

After this I ran

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

After reboot everything was OK.